# Workflow to work on a github fork of a python library?

Tags: python, github, pip

I want to contribute some changes to a python package which is using github. I have forked it. 
It is a library I am using in a project (in a python 3.5.1 virtual environment).

The documentation at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support tell me how to install from a github fork, and it goes on to mention "editable installs" (https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) which basically does "development mode"

If it is a pure python package does it matter if I skip editable mode?

(since there would be no build steps necessary as I would only be changing python code. This would mean I can keep using the same import statements.)

Comment: This is per-se a very interesting question, but probably a bit too broad for stackoverflow's question-answer format.

Comment: Oh. I will edit my question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you `pip install` **without** editable mode, the package is copied into your Python environment (such as `env/lib/python3.5/site-packages`). You can, of course, edit it right there, as it’s usually just a bunch of Python files, but that is inconvenient.

When you `pip install` **with** editable mode, `pip` only sets up a link from your environment to wherever the source code is. So, you can clone your GitHub fork into a convenient directory like `~/projects/libraryX`, then do `pip install -e ~/projects/libraryX`, and keep editing the code at `~/projects/libraryX` while your changes are immediately reflected in the environment where you installed it.

This all applies to pure Python packages.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the part about the install being a link. That makes a lot more sense now..